# Getting paintComponent elements of a JPanel to work with another JPanel inside of it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` with a simple animated snow particle effect inside of a `JFrame`, and it works from on its own. But when I try and add another panel to it, it makes the effect of the snow stop. Can anyone help me with this? Is it a problem with layering, or something? Or is it an issue with my Layout Managers?

My Code:

```
package christmasfinal;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChristmasFinal extends JApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        TreePanel treePanel = new TreePanel();
        frame.setSize(550, 420);
        SnowBackgroundPanel snowPanel = new SnowBackgroundPanel(frame.getWidth(),    frame.getHeight());
        treePanel.setSize(200, 320);
        snowPanel.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        snowPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(snowPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        snowPanel.add(treePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        System.out.println(treePanel.getWidth() + " " + treePanel.getHeight());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Christmas Final");
    }

}


package christmasfinal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TreePanel extends JPanel{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int[] treeX = {getWidth()/2, getWidth()/2-20, getWidth()/2-60, getWidth()/2-20,
        getWidth()/2-40, getWidth()/2-80, getWidth()/2-20, getWidth()/2-60, getWidth()/2-100,
        getWidth()/2+100,getWidth()/2+60, getWidth()/2+20, getWidth()/2+80,
        getWidth()/2+40, getWidth()/2+20, getWidth()/2+60, getWidth()/2+20, getWidth()/2};

        int[] treeY = {getHeight()/2-120, getHeight()/2-80, getHeight()/2-40, getHeight()/2-40,
        getHeight()/2-20, getHeight()/2, getHeight()/2, getHeight()/2+40, getHeight()/2+60,
        getHeight()/2+60, getHeight()/2+40, getHeight()/2, getHeight()/2, getHeight()/2-20,
        getHeight()/2-40, getHeight()/2-40, getHeight()/2-80, getHeight()/2-120};

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillPolygon(treeX, treeY, treeX.length);
        g.setColor(new Color(102, 51, 0));
        g.fillRect(getWidth()/2-20, getHeight()/2+60, 40, 40);
    }
}

package christmasfinal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;

public class SnowBackgroundPanel extends JPanel{
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Create ArrayList for SnowParticles
    ArrayList<SnowParticle> snow = new ArrayList();

    //Create animation timer
    Timer timer = new Timer(7, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });



    public SnowBackgroundPanel(int width, int height){
        setSize(width, height);
        System.out.println(getHeight() + " " + getWidth());
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
            snow.add(new SnowParticle());
            snow.get(i).x = rand.nextInt(getWidth()+1);
            snow.get(i).y = 0-rand.nextInt(getHeight()+1);
        }
        timer.start();

}
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //Set, paint, and move snow particles
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
            g.fillOval(snow.get(i).x, snow.get(i).y, 10, 10);
            snow.get(i).y += 1;
            if(snow.get(i).y > getHeight()){
                snow.get(i).x = rand.nextInt(getWidth()+1);
                snow.get(i).y = 0-rand.nextInt(getHeight()+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your TreePanel to the BorderLayout.CENTER position of the SnowPanel which will effectively cover up the SnowPanel, so it should be expected to cover SnowPanel's graphics and animation. Likely setting TreePanel to be non-opaque by calling `setOpaque(false)` on it will allow you to see through it:

```
  TreePanel treePanel = new TreePanel();
  treePanel.setOpaque(false);
```

Other issues with your code:

- Why have ChristmasFinal extend JApplet when it has no applet code nor behaviors?
- Avoid calling `setSize(...)` on anything as that is a dangerous thing to do.
- Better to let the components size themselves based on their layout managers and preferredSizes.
- If you absolutely need to set a size, better to override `getPreferredSize()`
- You should avoid having program logic within a `paintComponent(...)` method since you never have complete control over when or even if `paintComponent(...)` gets called.

Comment: plus one, but I'd have approached this an [entirely different way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27210137/418556)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: and your way looks to be cleaner than mine. plus one

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an entirely different approach:

- `SnowBackgroundPanel` & `TreePanel` which extend `JPanel` should instead implement `Drawable`
- The `Drawable` interface will have a single method `draw(Graphics2D g, Dimension sizeOfParent)`
- In the `draw()` method, put what was in `paintComponent()`
- In the single area designated for custom painting, (e.g. `RenderingSurface extends JPanel`) keep a collection of the drawn elements in a list that respects their order. e.g. if the first element is the BG, it is rendered first.
- In the `paintComponent()` of `RenderingSurface`, iterate the collection of drawable elements and draw each one.