# ContentPanel issue, The content panel is not showing up on the second window when I enter the information

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

This program takes user input for courses and outputs the best possible course that they should research for their post-secondary options. The issue is basically when I Fill in this information in the surveyFrame which is functional I know that,
Program name: Actuarial Science
Institution: University of Waterloo
Faculty: Faculty of Math
Program Duration (years): 4
Guidline: 88
Tuition Fee ($): 123456

Then a new frame should open with three panels that show each course that is related to their input.

All I need help with is that the panels don't show up and the contentPanel Panel objects are all throwing errors.

```
/* Note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209669/getting-paintcomponent-
 * elements-of-a-jpanel-to-work-with-another-jpanel-inside-o: used from line 48 to 50
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ResultJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton backButton;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JLabel header;
    JPanel headerPanel;
    JPanel tempPanel;
    JLabel options;
    JPanel optionsPanel;
    Box optionsBox1;
    JPanel contentPanel;
    BufferedImage img;
    
    ResultJFrame() {
        setTitle("Results");
        setSize(1000, 625);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/background.png"));

            contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
                }
            };
            
            header = new JLabel("Recommended Programs");
            header.setFont(new Font("Canva Sans", Font.BOLD, 30));
            header.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            headerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            headerPanel.setOpaque(false);
            headerPanel.add(header);
            contentPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            tempPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            options = new JLabel("Option 1                        Option 2" +
                    "                        Option 3");
            options.setFont(new Font("Canva Sans", Font.BOLD, 30));
            options.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            tempPanel.add(options);
            tempPanel.setOpaque(false);
            tempPanel.setBounds(-15, 60, 1000, 200);
            contentPanel.add(tempPanel);
            
            optionsBox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
            optionsBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));

            optionsPanel = new JPanel();
            optionsPanel.setOpaque(false);
            optionsPanel.add(optionsBox1);
            contentPanel.add(optionsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            backButton = new JButton("Go Back");
            backButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            backButton.setBackground(new Color(0, 21, 79));
            backButton.setFocusable(false);
            backButton.addActionListener(this);
            backButton.setFont(new Font("Canva Sans", Font.BOLD, 30));

            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
            backButton.setBounds(397, 460, 180, 60);
            backButton.setBackground(new Color(0, 21, 79));
            buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
            buttonPanel.add(backButton);
            contentPanel.add(buttonPanel);

            setContentPane(contentPanel);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Actuarial(int option) {
        JPanel options = new JPanel();
        options.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
        options.setBackground(Color.RED);
        add(options);
        
        JPanel backPlate1 = new JPanel();
        backPlate1.setLayout(null);
        backPlate1.setBounds(74, 120, 200, 370);
        backPlate1.setBackground(new Color(1, 28, 102));
        backPlate1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 350));
        contentPanel.add(backPlate1);
        backPlate1.setVisible(true);
                        
        JPanel backPlate2 = new JPanel();
        backPlate2.setLayout(null);
        backPlate2.setBounds(387, 120, 200, 370);
        backPlate2.setBackground(new Color(1, 28, 102));
        backPlate2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 350));
        contentPanel.add(backPlate2);
        backPlate2.setVisible(true);
              
        JPanel backPlate3 = new JPanel();
        backPlate3.setLayout(null);
        backPlate3.setBounds(697, 120, 200, 370);
        backPlate3.setBackground(new Color(1, 28, 102));
        backPlate3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 350));
        contentPanel.add(backPlate3);
        backPlate3.setVisible(true);
            
        contentPanel.add(backPlate1);
        contentPanel.add(backPlate2);
        contentPanel.add(backPlate3);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == backButton) {
            this.dispose();
            TitleFrame titleFrame = new TitleFrame();
            titleFrame.getClass();
            //go back to title frame
        }
    }

    public static void ComputationalMathematics(int i) {
        
    }
}
```

Expecting 3 panels with the courses.

Comment: 1) *all throwing errors.* - and the error are? 2) Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 3) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 4) Post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test to see the described behaviour.